# javascript captcha not validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, captcha

i have a html form with captcha validation and i am using java script to create a captcha. it inputs the captcha value from java script into input feild but it don't validate on button click and post the form. below i put the link to fiddle

```
    <form action="/Admin/Public/FormMailer.aspx" method="post" id="FormSave1" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FormSave1" style="margin-top:20px">
        <input type="hidden" name="FM_Charset" value="iso-8859-1" /> <input type="hidden" name="FM_html" value="true" />
        <input type="hidden" name="FM_Subject" value="E-mail from my website" /> <input type="hidden" name="FM_FromEmail" value="" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="FM_FromName" value="Dynamicweb FORMAILER" />
        <input type="hidden" name="FM_Template" value="Mail.html" /> <input type="hidden" name="FM_ToEmail" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="FM_ToEmail" value="" />
<table>
        <tbody>
<tr>
<td>INDTAST TALLET HERUNDER</td>
<td><input type="text" id="txtCaptcha" style="background-image:url(1.jpg); text-align:center; border:none;font-weight:bold; font-size: 16px;" disabled="">
</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td><td></td><td>
 <input type="text" id="txtInput" style="margin-left: 20px; text-align: center;" required>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <td>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="ValidCaptcha();">
 </td>
</tbody></table>
     </form>
```

java script

```
    function DrawCaptcha()
  {
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var code = a + '' + b + '' + '' + c + '' + d + '' + e + ''+ f + '' + g;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code
      }

      // Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function
    function ValidCaptcha(){
      var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);

    if (str1 == str2) {
      //TRUE
      $("form").submit();
    } else {
      //FALSE
      alert("TALLET ER FORKERT!");
    }

  }

  // Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
  function removeSpaces(string)
  {
    return string.split(' ').join('');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    DrawCaptcha();
    javascript:enableField()
      });
```

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6JpA/)

Comment: What is suppose to do: `javascript:enableField()` ??? It's missing in your jsfiddle

Comment: if i remove [javascript:enableField()] the code is still working.... but what could be the reason ? it posting a page without validation

Comment: fixed jsfiddle, should works as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6JpA/1/

Comment: @A. Wolff you are the boss man ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all: Captcha should be validated server side, not in javascript. In your case everyone can submit form manually without even entering anything in captcha field.
- Second thing: Captcha should not be in text form(!). Every person who would like to break it, would just copy automatically the text.

So, your Captcha is totally usless. It is irritating for real users and doesn't secure at all against automatic requests.

---

And as for your question:

-> Change your validate function:

```
if (str1 == str2) {
  //TRUE
  return 1;
} else {
  //FALSE
  alert("TALLET ER FORKERT!");
  return 0;
}
```

-> And add this code in document ready function:

```
document.getElementById('FormSave1').onsubmit = function() {
    if(!ValidCaptcha())
       return false;
}
```

-> Remove inline onclick event for submit button.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qZFBc/)

**Please note that onsubmit event won't work from inline script, it has to be assigned this way**

Comment: "So, your Captcha is totally usless." +1

Comment: you are 100% rite but because of some reason i cant do serverside scripting so i have to choose this way for my solution. but any how can you tell me the reason why it is doing that??